# SQL Server Index and Statistics Maintenance -- IndexOptimize ola hallengren Script

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, ssms

I am using IndexOptimize script by Ola Hallengren and am having problems. I have set this up using the parameters below. I read online you have to specify all parameters in order for this to work which I have done. I have put this stored procedure into a database and am calling it in a job. The job runs successfully but it is not rebuilding or reorganizing the indexes.

Please see my code below can any help.

```
USE TestDBA
EXEC [OlaH].[usp_IndexOptimize]

@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
@FragmentationLow  = NULL,
@FragmentationMedium  = 'INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
@FragmentationHigh  = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
@FragmentationLevel1  = 5,
@FragmentationLevel2  = 30,
@PageCountLevel  = 0,
@SortInTempdb = 'Y',
@MaxDOP = NULL,
@FillFactor = NULL,
@PadIndex = NULL,
@LOBCompaction  = 'Y',
@UpdateStatistics = 'ALL',
@OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y',
@StatisticsSample = NULL,
@StatisticsResample = 'N',
@PartitionLevel = 'Y',
@MSShippedObjects = 'Y',
@Indexes = NULL,
@TimeLimit = 360,
@Delay = NULL,
@WaitAtLowPriorityMaxDuration = 5,
@WaitAtLowPriorityAbortAfterWait  = 'SELF',
@LockTimeout = NULL,
@LogToTable = 'N',
@Execute = 'Y'
```

Comment: did you try to change the `@PageCountLevel`?

Comment: Check the actual level of fragmentation on your indexes, they might not need rebuilding. Frag a table then re-run the script. (I'm assuming you're testing this in DEV)

Comment: This is being tested in DEV and yes i have the default value for pagecount is 1000 i have changed to @PageCountLevel  = 0

Answer (score 0):

You issue is likely  the fact that you have `@TimeLimit = 360` which is the seconds after which no commands are executed. That's not a long time for this job. This likely is preventing the script from finishing gathering the fragmentation statistics, and thus never makes it to the reindex, reorganize, rebuild steps. 6 minutes is pretty small window for a decent size database. Set this to something more realistic, like 3600, which is 1 hour.

Aside from that, the fragmentation level could be a second culprit.

```
@FragmentationLevel1  = 5,
@FragmentationLevel2  = 30,
```

This means if the fragmentation is between 5% and 30%, then it will perform the actions in `@FragmentationMedium`. If it's greater than 30% then it will perform what you have listed in `@FragmentationHigh`.  If your indexes aren't fragmented at least 5%, nothing is going to happen since you have `@FragmentationLow = NULL`.

You can check this with [`sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-physical-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(ips.OBJECT_ID)
 ,i.NAME
 ,ips.index_id
 ,index_type_desc
 ,avg_fragmentation_in_percent
 ,avg_page_space_used_in_percent
 ,page_count
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, 'SAMPLED') ips
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON (ips.object_id = i.object_id)
 AND (ips.index_id = i.index_id)
ORDER BY avg_fragmentation_in_percent DESC
```

[Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4606787/benjamin-moskovits) brought up a good point. After 5 minutes of waiting for low priority locks, the script would abort the online index rebuild operation since you have `@WaitAtLowPriorityAbortAfterWait = 'SELF'`. This shouldn't affect every table in your database though. However, if you specifically fragmented an index by adding a bunch of data or playing with the fill factor, and this is the only index that meets your threshold and a lock is holding onto it, it could result in this behavior.

Comment: did your suggestions and it still has not worked @scsimon

Comment: how long did the job run for @Ap9_Jacka

Comment: I bet a table being used by Ola Hallengren's  (very well regarded) script is locked by a deamon script that is just running and running so Ola's script is blocked.

Comment: @Ap9_Jacka did the job run for over an hour and does the query above return Indexes that are fragmented a least 10%